# 'Cannot GET' on Express when using proxy pass in Nginx

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, https

I'm running two websites on a DigitalOcean droplet, and now I've upgraded to https on both of them. On one of the sites I'm doing a request to a node server I'm running on there to send emails, but since I've enabled https it blocks this request because it isn't https (logically). So I tried to use the node mailserver as a proxy pass on one of the sites that has https enabled.

To test, my node server I want to proxy pass looks like this:

```
exports.start = () => {
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));
    app.listen(4004, () => console.log('Server listening on port 4004'));
};

this.start();
```

My Nginx `sites-enabled/default` looks like this:

```
server {

server_name mywebsite.nl www.website.nl;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://<PIVATE IP>:4000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /ws {
    proxy_pass http://<PIVATE IP>:4002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
}


location /mailmeister {
            proxy_pass http://<PIVATE IP>:4004;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
}


listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.nl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.nl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

So the `/mailmeister` is where I want to redirect all requests to the node server to.
When I run `curl localhost:4004` or `curl PRIVATE IP:4004` I get the expected
`Hello World!` response. But when I run `curl https://mywebsite.nl/mailmeister` It returns a webpage that says

```
Cannot GET /mailmeister
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `curl localhost:4004/mailmeister` should return the same 404.  So you need to either configure the node.js to route `/mailmeister` or configure nginx to reduce the path to `/` see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: This worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, since you have:

```
location /mailmeister {
            proxy_pass http://<PIVATE IP>:4004;
}
```

It should be handled like so:

```
app.get('/mailmeister ', (req, res) => res.send('Hallo World!'));
```

Not tested this particular setup. There is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69991280/5362795) where this is explained further. Once you get it, the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) makes more sense.