# Why do I get 404 on nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below is my config and I'm getting 404 on all routes defined apart from the `well-known` route and I don't understand why.

If I make a request to http://example.tech/connect I get a 404 and if I make a request to http://api.example.tech I also get a 404.

I can't see where I've gone wrong as this looks like it should work!

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  warn;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #REMOVE REFERENCE TO FILES THAT HAVE  "server" and "location" blocks in them so we can do it all in this file
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # issue with ip and the nginx proxy
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.tech;

        location /.well-known/openid-configuration {
            proxy_pass https://myapp.net;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            client_max_body_size 10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_buffers 32 4k;
        }

        location /connect {
            proxy_pass https://myapp.net;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            client_max_body_size 10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_buffers 32 4k;
        }

        location /auth {
            proxy_pass https://myapp.net;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            client_max_body_size 10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_buffers 32 4k;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name api.example.tech;

        location /auth/ {
            proxy_pass https://myapp.net;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            #proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            client_max_body_size 10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_buffers 32 4k;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need a specific uri in `proxy_pass` directive, not a backslash. But in your case here, a backslash is acting as the specific uri. Nginx replaces `'/auth'`(for example) with `'/'`(you've added).

In fact, the answer you put is right, turning `proxy_pass http://myapp.net;` to `proxy_pass http://myapp.net/;`.

The reason is that `proxy_pass` would work in two different ways with/without a specific uri. [More details about this directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) on nginx.org. Blow is some content quoted in that link.

> - If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>     matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
>   location /name/ {
>         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
>     }
> - If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original
>     request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed
>     when processing the changed URI:
>
>   location /some/path/ {
>         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
>     }

In your case, without URI in `proxy_pass` directive, so `/auth` would be passed to backend server. Unfortunately, your backend server does not have the `/auth` resource, so 404 is returned. If your backend server does have `/auth` to be processed, you would never get 404 error while requesting uri `/auth`.

Answer (score 4):

Needed a forward slash on the end of the proxy_pass for some reason

Answer (score 4):

Here are two examples, which hopefully clarify things.

```
 location /some-path {
    proxy_pass http://server:3000;
 }
```

In this case the [proxied server](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) (target) must handle the route `/some-path`. If handling something else, like `/` only, it will return an error to Nginx.

One solution is to add a trailing `/` e.g.:

```
 location /some-path {
    proxy_pass http://server:3000/;
 }
```

Now requests sent to `/some-path` can (and must) be handled by the route `/` on the proxied server side. However, this may cause issues with some servers. For example, with *Express*, `curl localhost/some-path` would be handled fine by Express, whereas `curl localhost/some-path/` would cause Express to return `Cannot GET //`.

This might be different for your target server, but the principle is the same: if you specify the server only, the full path in `location` is passed to the server, so it must be handled accordingly.

Comment: This anwser saved me!! Thanks a lot for explaining this with proxy pass, trailing slash excatly what I needed - stackoverflow give this guy a medal

Answer (score 0):

This is my case how I've get 404 instead of 502:

```
# let's define some proxy pass
location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5080; # this backend doesn't exist which leads to 502
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

# this is a default directives
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html; # this is a reason to redirect 502 to 50x.html
location = /50x.html { # but this file doesn't exist in root so we get 404 instead of 502
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```